# timer function in javascript

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any method to capture the time taken from the alert message displayed till the users action to confirm the message using javascript

Comment: At least take the time to phrase a half decent question.

Comment: I have reframed the question. Is that ok?

Comment: Your Question is not descriptive ,be simple.Avoid Large sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a timer in Javascript when you display the message. Stop the timer when the user acknowledges the message. Use AJAX to submit the time to your PHP/CodeIgniter app.

Start a timer when you are going to ask a question on StackOverflow. Don't submit questions that take less than 5 seconds to write.

Comment: Thanks you gave me the clue.Here's the clue,
<code> var timer = {
    time: 0,
    now: function(){ return (new Date()).getTime(); },
    start: function(){ this.time = this.now(); },
    since: function(){ return this.now()-this.time; }
    }
    timer.start(); // start counting my friend...
    /*
    do some amazing stuff with jQuery or any other JavaScript library
    */
    alert('I did all that in ' + timer.since() + 'ms');